# Unable to perform action on the Context menu options

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to perform some actions from the right-click menu items. if I try the below sequence is not performed on the context menu rather it's performed on the google auto suggestive option.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("gLFyf")).SendKeys("Mytest");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.ContextClick(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("gLFyf"))).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
```

[image]
Ex: Here I'm trying to click on paste,
Could you please tell me what is the best way to work on right-click menu items? some menus are hidden how we have to count the items?

Comment: if the options that appear aren't in the DOM (they won't be if it's the browser's menu) then Selenium can't interact with them.  You could use a robot or something like that, but what option are you trying to get to here?

Comment: Updated my query, Yes, it's the browser menu these actions are not available in the DOM, and trying using C# @pcalkins

Comment: If paste is what you want, use ctrl-v to paste.  (element.SendKeys...)

Comment: I have to perform similar actions on other pages as well where we don't have the Shortcut keys.